Prove This $*$-algebra is a Hopf $*$-algebra
I came across the following lemma while reading a paper, and I would really appreciate a detailed proof of the claim, since the proof is omitted.

Let $A$ be a unital $*$-algebra with all of the basic ingredients for a Hopf $*$-algebra.  Namely, $A$ possesses a comultiplication $\Delta: A \longrightarrow A \odot A$ satisfying: $$(\Delta \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta = (\text{id}_A \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$$ along with linear maps $\epsilon: A \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $S:A \longrightarrow A$ satisfying: $$(\epsilon \otimes \text{id}) \circ \Delta = (\text{id} \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta = \text{id}_A$$ and: $$m(S \otimes \text{id}) \circ \Delta = m(\text{id} \otimes S) \circ \Delta = \epsilon(\cdot)1_A$$ where $m: A \odot A \longrightarrow A$ by $m(a \otimes b) = ab$. $\textbf{Prove that $A$ is infact a Hopf $*$-algebra}$.  I.e, that $\epsilon$ is a $*$-homomorphism and that $S(ab)=S(b)S(a)$ with $S(S(a^{*})^{*})=a$.

I have been able to show that $\epsilon$ is $*$-preserving without issue and that $S(S(a^{*})^{*})=a$, but the rest of the identities I'm a bit lost on what to do.  Both identities seem possible to prove if I assume one of them to be true to prove the others.  However I can't seem to see how to prove both that $\epsilon$ is multiplicative and that $S$ is anti-multiplicative at the same time.
A detailed explanation that's friendly to non-experts (so hopefully just moving symbols around) would be great!
$\textbf{Edit}:$ So apparently there is a proof of this fact in a 1993 paper "Dual Pairs of Hopf $*$-algebras" from Alfons Van Daele, but there doesn't seem to be a copy of this paper anywhere online that I can find.  So if someone has a copy/link to this paper, that would be greatly appreciated.

Is the comultiplication already assumed to be a $\ast$-homomorphism?

Yes it is assumed to be.

https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/blms/25.3.209?sid=vendor%3Adatabase

Here is a screenshot of the relevant parts of Alfons van Daele’s paper:


Here is a translation of the proof for $\epsilon$ being multiplicative into a form that requires no familiarity with the usual way Hopf algebra people write arguments. Admittedly, this form is even harder to understand intuitively, but should be clear formally, so I’d suggest mainly using this form as a way to understand how the original argument actually works:
We begin by recalling that multiplicativity of $\Delta$ can be expressed as $\Delta \circ m = (m \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \Delta)$ where $B: A \otimes A \to A \otimes A$ flips the two tensor components. Co-associativity of $\Delta$ can be expressed as $(\Delta \otimes \iota) \circ \Delta = (\iota \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$. Associativity of $m$ can be expressed as $m \circ (m \otimes \iota) = m \circ (\iota \otimes m)$. We also write $u: \mathbb{C} \to A$ for the map $u(\lambda) = \lambda 1$. Then the axiom on the antipode $S$ can be stated as $m \circ (S \otimes \iota) \circ \Delta = m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ \Delta = u \circ \epsilon$, and the fact that $1$ is the unity of $A$ can be stated as $m \circ (\iota \otimes u) = m \circ (u \otimes \iota) = \iota$.
We first observe that,
$$\begin{split}
(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ \Delta \circ m = m &= m \circ ([(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ \Delta] \otimes [(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ \Delta])\\
&= m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \Delta)
\end{split} \tag{1}$$
Now, we apply $\iota \otimes \Delta$ on $A \otimes A$, then $(1)$ to the first two tensor components while applying $S$ to the third tensor component, and then finally $m$,
$$\begin{split}
&(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota)\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the unity }u\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the co-unit }\epsilon\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the antipode }S\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (m \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by associativity}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by co-associativity}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by multiplicativity of }\Delta\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by}(1)\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by co-associativity}\\
= &m \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes m) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by associativity}\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \iota \otimes S) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \Delta) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the antipode }S\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the co-unit }\epsilon\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes u) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the unity }u
\end{split} \tag{2}$$
As a needed observation before proceeding further, note that the $m$ in $(\iota \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B)$ multiplies the second and third tensor components that we started with before flipping, i.e.,
$$(\iota \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B) = (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes m \otimes \iota) \tag{3}$$
Now, we apply $\Delta \otimes \iota$ on $A \otimes A$, then $(2)$ to the first and third tensor components while applying $S$ to the second tensor component, and then finally $m$,
$$\begin{split}
&u \circ \epsilon \circ m\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes u) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes u \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes u \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the co-unit }\epsilon\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the antipode }S\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by co-associativity}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes m) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by }(3)\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (m \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\iota \otimes S) \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes B) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by }(2)\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &m \circ (\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes B) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by co-associativity}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\iota \otimes m \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \iota \otimes S \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \Delta \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\iota \otimes u \otimes \iota) \circ (\iota \otimes \epsilon \otimes \iota) \circ (\Delta \otimes \iota) \;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the antipode }S\\
= &(\epsilon \otimes \iota \otimes \epsilon) \circ (\iota \otimes u \otimes \iota)\;\;\; \text{ by the axiom on the co-unit }\epsilon\\
= &u \circ (\epsilon \otimes \epsilon) \;\;\; \text{ rearranging}
\end{split}$$
Since $u$ is injective, this implies $\epsilon \circ m = \epsilon \otimes \epsilon$, which is exactly multiplicativity of $\epsilon$.

Could you outline what 'multiply with $S(b_{(3)})$' is doing exactly?

@Isochron I’m not an expert in Hopf algebras either. This is their preferred way of writing stuff. It boils down to first applying comultiplication then applying the previous formula to the first component. I’ll write down a more detailed version later if you want.

That would be nice.  So you mean apply $\Delta$ to both sides of the first equation line?

@Isochron No, it’s more applying $\Delta$ first, then applying the first equation. I just edited to add a translation of the proof of multiplicativity of $\epsilon$, avoiding this “multiply with $S(b_{(3)})$” thing. Honestly, this translated proof is far more incomprehensible intuitively (there’s a reason why people in Hopf algebras write the way they do, after all), but at least you can verify its formal correctness. It might be better for you to consider this “formal” version of the proof as a way to clarify what the original version meant, rather than as a replacement for the original.

Hmm this is alot, I will have to look over this tomorrow.  If it works, then that's sufficient, but do know what the author is saying with the $S(b_{(3)})$ thing?  I thought perhaps they were just applying a simple identity.

@Isochron It is the step in (2) marked with “by (1)”. My translated version follows the original proof, just formalized. It might be easier to explain once you read the formal version, but what it means is basically that you first apply $\iota \otimes \Delta$ on $A \otimes A$, then apply the previous formula (which says two maps from $A \otimes A$ to $A$ coincide) to the first two tensor components, and the finally multiply everything together (i.e., apply $m$).

After going through the details, this seems to check out.  How did you manage to come up the identities you would need, translate them into formulas involving tensor products of the maps, and then do this long string of computations to arrive at the solution?  I don't see how you would think of all of these steps to arrive at the solution.

@Isochron It is fundamentally just a translation of the original proof. So once you know what is happening in the original proof you have some guiding principles from which you can more or less guess what needs to be done in the formal version. As I said, multiplying $S(b_{(3)})$ amounts to starting by applying $\iota\otimes\Delta$, then applying the previous formula to the first two tensor components (i.e., the previous formula $\otimes\iota$), while applying $S$ to the third component (i.e., $\iota\otimes\iota\otimes S$), then multiplying everything together (i.e., applying $m$). The reason…

@Isochron … we want to “multiply by $S(b_{(3)})$” is because we want $S(b_{(3)})$ to cancel $b_{(2)}$ in the first formula, by the axiom on $S$. The original formula applies comultiplication to the second component, so in a sense the new formula will apply $\Delta$ and then $\Delta\otimes\iota$ to the second component (the $b$ part), i.e., we would go from $b$ to $b_{(1,1)}\otimes b_{(1,2)}\otimes b_{(2)}$. But you want to use $S$ to cancel the second and third components, so you need to apply co-associativity once. After that you should get $b_{(1)}\otimes b_{(2,1)}\otimes b_{(2,2)}$, and…

@Isochron … you can then apply $\iota\otimes\iota\otimes S$ and then $\iota\otimes m$ to cancel the final two components. So this means, in order to simplify both sides of the formula to the end form of (2) (the formula $\sum_{(a)}\epsilon(a_{(1)}b)a_{(2)}=\sum_{(a)}\epsilon(a_{(1)})\epsilon(b)a_{(2)}$ in the original proof), you need to first move two applications of $\Delta$ together, then apply co-associativity, then move the application of $S$ and one application of $m$ (on the correct tensor components) to just before applications of $\Delta$, then apply the axiom on $S$, then just use…

@Isochron … axioms on $\epsilon$ and $u$ to clean up. Everything that was done in my formal version started at the middle and used those basic guiding principles to calculate to the two ends, and whatever formulas and axioms that were needed to move $\Delta$, $S$, and $m$ to the required positions just got formalized and added in throughout the process. The same process applies to the second part, i.e., multiplying by $S(a_{(3)})$.
